# How do I access attribute directive on component from abstract class?

Tags: angular

I have an abstract base class that looks like this:

```
export abstract class BaseComponentClass{
   // implementation here
}
```

Then I have a bunch of custom components that extend this base component like so:

```
export class ImageComponent extends BaseComponentClass implements OnInit, OnChanges {

}
```

It is on these custom components what I also have an attribute directive. So on the `ImageComponent`, in the template it looks like:

```
<app-ofc-image identityBox></app-ofc-image>
```

How do I access the `identityBox` directive from my `BaseComponent` abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the directive into your custom component and then pass it into the super constructor of the abstract class.

For example, in my `ImageComponent` example above, here is my constructor:

```
constructor(protected el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, ibox: IdentityBoxDirective){
    super(el, ibox);
  }
```

Now you have it available to you in the abstract class like so:

```
constructor(protected el: ElementRef, private ibox: IdentityBoxDirective){}
```